# I get the alert as wrong.Any other logic if I want to compare the clickedcolor is equal to pickedcolor?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

This is my code for a function where I want to check if I picked the correct color of the square on my html page to my pre-selected color of the choice (in the given case it is color[5])

But I always get the answer as wrong, as I checked that.

Even if I use

```
var check = (clickedColor === pickedColor);
alert(check);
```

the above code returns false every-time.

I can't find where my logic is going wrong.
Here is my code:-

```js
var colors = [
  "rgb(0,0,255)",
  "rgb(0,255,255)",
  "rgb(255,0,255)",
  "rgb(255,255,0)",
  "rgb(0,255,0)",
  "rgb(255,0,0)"
];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var pickedColor = colors[5];
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
Squaref();


function Squaref() {
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    ///////populate
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
    ////// check picked colors
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      //////grab
      var clickedColor = this.style.background;
      ////////compare
      if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
        alert(correct);
      } else {
        alert("Wrong");
      }
    });
  };
};
```

```css
.square {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="colorDisplay"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to use `this.style.backgroundColor` instead of `this.style.background`, and the output of that has spaces between the values (`rgb(255, 0, 0)`), so you will either have to add spaces to the values in your `colors` array or use the `#ff0000` format.

And you have to alert `"correct"`, not `correct`: `alert("correct");`

```js
var colors = [
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var pickedColor = colors[5];
colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
Squaref();


function Squaref() {
  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    ///////populate
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
    ////// check picked colors
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      //////grab
      var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
      ////////compare
      if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
        alert("correct");
      } else {
        alert("Wrong");
      }
    });
  };
};
```

```css
.square {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="colorDisplay"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Its the spaces between the values (rgb(255, 0, 0)) which was causing the problem.